# Is the outcome of a roulette spin independent of prior outcomes? Why?

Tags: probability, gambling

Red and black on roulette table (without green "0"). The outcome is independent of prior outcomes, right? It does not matter how many times in a row black (or red) comes up prior, the outcome is still random and 50/50. What is the formula that proves this?

Old question, but still unclear and would like to have an answer.

Comment: Ethan's answer is an excellent answer if we assume that the roulette wheel is fair. I just would like to add that if in reality, you are playing roulette, and red comes up 100 times in a row, then I would say that you have a pretty darn good reason to believe the roulette wheel is *not* fair, and is more likely to come up with red than black. So, for your next bet, I would bet red again!

Comment: AND I think u are wrong, haha ! EVEN if it is a fair or UNfair wheel it makes NO difference .. u got caught in your own reverse logic with an UNfair wheel it does not make the opposite bet come more often than the UNFAIR probability was before it showed either red or black more times in a row ... NO ?

Comment: I didn't say to place the bet on rhe opposite ... that would be the gambler's fallacy. I said that if it cane up red 100 times in a row, I would bet red * again*, since I now have reason to believe the wheel is unfair, and that red is more likely to come up for this wheel

Comment: OK. Good. Our brains are funny in looking at recent events as predictor of future happenings. Worked in nature perhaps when pattern was a way to avoid getting eaten, but NOT random (50/50%) events, haha ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Right. But there is no "formula" to prove it. That's the definition of a fair wheel - it has no memory of what came before. Each spin is a fresh start.

The same is true for flipping a fair coin. There's no difference between flipping one coin ten times or ten coins all at once. In each case it's 50/50 for each toss independent of the others.

It is true that if you flip a fair coin over and over again in the long run you see half heads and half tails on average. But that's not because the coin thinks it has to catch up after a run of one kind or the other.

There's some serious mathematics that tells you how many flips you should make in order to be within some interval around 50/50 with, say, $90\%$ probability.

Comment: Thanks. HARD to convince even highly educated people it is so, haha !

Answer (score 0):

And AGAIN there is no 90% probability of a switch or the number of times in a row of any series like the one here comes up 1 ... n times in a row, as it is NOT CONDITIONAL on the earlier outcome(s) .... Einstein did provide the proof here mathematically but I can't find it. Anyone knows where I can find it ?

Comment: There can't be a mathematical proof about how the world behaves. This can be proved in a mathematical model of the world. It was proved long before Einstein about the mathematical model that's behind pretty much all of everyday physics, so gives us a reliable way to predict how real coins behave.

Comment: Yes, agree. But there is an infinity calculation that can be applied to this specific problem that proves the outcome is still random even after "n" times of the same coming up. BTW the doubling of your bet each time you lose is the ONLY way to win, but goes quickly in to stratospheric numbers ($), and in the end you still only win 1$ IF you started with that bet. eg. Bet $1, $2, $4, $8, $16 (losses all), then $32 and WIN $32 + Your bet back. So lost $31, got bet back $32 + $32 win = $1  Risk is too great after just a  few (10 ?) of the same color bet being a losing one, for a minuscule $1 win